# Date time stamp query in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

I am a SQL beginner and had a query to find the ID of the person who booked the last sales in MAY 2015, the `occurred_at` column is a `datetime` (2015-10-06 17:31:14) and I do not know how to get the last sales booked in May 2015 from that.

This is my query below and it says there is no column as `Sales_Date`.  Please help

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    CAST(occurred_at AS time) AS sales_time,
    CONCAT(' ', CAST(occurred_at AS DATE)) AS Sales_Date,
    extract(year from sales_date) AS year, 
    extract(month from sales_date) AS Month  
FROM
    <table name >
WHERE 
    year = 2015 AND month = 05 
ORDER BY 
    sales_time DESC
```

Comment: how is it possible "the last sales in MAY 2015 , the occurred_at column is a datetime stamp (2015-10-06 17:31:14)". Or it is just incorrect example ?

Comment: What is the data type of column *occurred_at* and which dbms you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last sales, why not just use MAX(occured_at) and year = 2015?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to extract the **year** and **month** on your **where** clause.

```
SELECT ID , CAST(occurred_at AS time ) AS sales_time  ,
       CONCAT ( ' ' , CAST(occurred_at AS DATE) ) AS Sales_Date ,
       extract ( year from sales_date) AS year , 
       extract ( month from sales_date) AS Month  
from <table name >
where extract(year from sales_date) = 2015 and extract(month from sales_date) = 5 
order by sales_time desc
```

Comment: thank you,  is it cos year = 2015 AND month = 05 cannot come in the WHERE  command as they are aggregate functions , so can i use HAVING

HAVING  year = 2015 AND month = 05